# Add Element after every second element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I got a list where i want to add a div after every second **list** element.
My problem is that the first element is a `span`.

I want to have it like this:

```
<ul class="timeline">
  <span class="topbullet"></span>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</ul>
```

But i get it like this:

```
<ul class="timeline">
  <span class="topbullet"></span>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JQuery Code i used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".timeline li:nth-child(2n)").add('.timeline li:last').after("<div class='clearfix'></div>");
})
```

Comment: what does the original html look like before you run the script?

Comment: Just a heads-up, list elements, like `ol` or `ul` should only contain list items (`li`) for valid markup.

Comment: `div` and `span` are not valid children of `ul`. I would not rely on this HTML working cross browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the [`:nth-of-type`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selector.

```js
$(".timeline li:nth-of-type(2n)")
  .add('.timeline li:last')
  .after("<div class='clearfix'></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="timeline">
  <span class="topbullet"></span>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `+1` to `2n`.

```
$(".timeline li:nth-child(2n+1)")
```

**demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".timeline li:nth-child(2n+1)").add('.timeline li:last').after("<div class='clearfix'>added div</div>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeline">
  <span class="topbullet"></span>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: good solution, thanks for your help! But i would prefer the answer of H77.